# The "git fetch" does nothing on repo

Tags: linux, git

I noticed with git log origin/master that new a commit is up.
So I want to "see" this commit on my local repo.

I do this

```
$ git fetch -v
From xxx.xxx:proj/test
= [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
```

Everything seems fine... But nothing has changed on my local repo !?

Comment: All git fetch does is get the remote tracking branches ... Is this not happening?  You are not meaning to do a `git pull` right??  Which is a combination of `git fetch` then `git merge`.

Comment: No, I just want to update the local repository...

Answer (score 2):

To update *your* branches (as opposed to your Git's memory of some *other* Git's branches—`git fetch` updates this memory only), you must run a *second* Git command.

The second command to run is sometimes `git merge` and sometimes `git rebase`, depending on how you prefer to work.  If you have no preference yet, use either one until you do have a preference.

There is a convenience command spelled `git pull`, that runs both `git fetch` and then the second command.  The second command it runs is the one you tell it to.  You must configure it based on your choice of second command to use.  I recommend avoiding this until you really understand what the second command is and does, because eventually something will go wrong when running the second command.  If you do not *know* that `git pull` is running this second command, you will not only not know what to do about this failure ... you won't even know that you need to look for how to fix problems with the *other command!*